# Show field when there is input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here's what I'm trying to achieve. http://codepen.io/ifen/pen/mBcCo

In mine http://jsbin.com/jafiwani/1/edit , when I enter something into the form and move on to the next, the box closes up and shows the default name. If you try to put anything into both forms you'll understand what I mean. Any help would be great, I've tried everything I know.

Comment: add this in css input[value=*]{visibility: visible}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing jQuery from that jsbin. If you go to "Add Library" at the top and add jQuery 2.1.0 you'll see that it works!

n.b you should always check out the javascript console (available in all browsers by viewing the developer tools) for any javascript errors to see what's going wrong. In this case it says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

This means that the jQuery library that much of the code here depends on (see anything with a $ - that's jQuery in action) is missing.